# Visual Studio Code - stopOnEntry does not work with python

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

i've try to use VSCode for my python development. Everything works fine, but i have one problem. The `stopOnEntry` debug settings seems not working.

At the moment my program always stops on the first line of the program if i hit F5, so i have to hit F5 again to run my entire program.

My wish:
Do not add a breakpoint at the start of my program, only if i set one.
Is this possible with VSCode and python?

Thanks in advance
Tonka

Comment: Hi, this is a bug in the extension and an issue has been raised against it. https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/168

Comment: Hi @tonka, this has been resolved in the latest version of the extension.

Comment: great :-D . thx Don